# proof based on AM-GM inequality

Tags: inequality

If $a^2 + b^2 = 1$, and $x^2 +y^2 = 1$, show that $ax + by<1$

---

since
$$a^2+b^2=1\implies (a^2+b^2) / 2 ≥  \sqrt{a^2b^2} \implies ab ≤  1/2$$
similarly $xy ≤ 1/2$.
Taking $ab$ and $xy$ at their greatest :

---

$$(ax+by)/2 ≥  \sqrt{1/2\cdot 1/2} \implies ax+by ≥  1$$
Please correct me where I am wrong. Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Please reformat with [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020). Inequalities such as $ab\ge\frac12$ have the wrong direction. Try e.g. $a=\frac35,\,b=\frac45$. But with Cauchy-Schwarz, you can prove $ax+by\le1$. As of your latest edit you incorrectly claim $ax+by<1$ holds in general, but it doesn't if $x=a,\,y=b$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1089301/42969 for various proofs.

Comment: @J.G. Yeah I can use Cauchy-Schwarz but our teacher hasn't taught it yet in class and this is an assignment based on AM-GM only, that's why it's better to use AM-GM only

Comment: Luckily, the top answer in @MartinR's link uses AM-GM in one step, with no use of C-S.